# Show / Hiding Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

After cobbling together a few questions I've managed to get this far to showing / hiding divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.box').hide();
  $('#categories').onMouseOver(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).val()).show();
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="categories">
 <div id="btn-top20"><a href="">Top 20 Villas</a></div>
 <div id="btn-villaspec"><a href="">Villa Specials</a></div>
 <div id="btn-staffpicks"><a href="">Our Staff Picks</a></div>
</div>

<div id="category-content">
 <div id="divarea1" class="box">
  Content 1
 </div>

 <div id="divarea2" class="box">
  Content 2
 </div>

 <div id="divarea3" class="box">
  Content 3
 </div>    
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Erm, how so "What am I missing"? What happens? What happens not?

Comment: one thing you're missing is that `#categories` is a `div` and does not have any `val()`. another is that the function is called `mouseover` not `onMouseOver`. other than that, you haven't specified what you want to happen. when `#categories` is hovered, you want to show what? i take it that you expect `$(this).val()` to be either `area1`, `area2` or `area3`, but what would be the magic logic to resolve those?

Comment: Are you trying to implement an accordion?  Check out jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
 <div id="btn-top20" rel="area1"><a href="">Top 20 Villas</a></div>
 <div id="btn-villaspec" rel="area2"><a href="">Villa Specials</a></div>
 <div id="btn-staffpicks" rel="area3"><a href="">Our Staff Picks</a></div>
```

with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#categories div').mouseenter(function() {
       $('.box').hide();
       $('#div' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
    });
});
```

Corrections:

- No such function onMouseHover.
- Attached the event to every div, not the `#categories` parent, so `this` has the right context.
- added `rel` for every div, because `val` is meaningless.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/ivuxo

You may also want to hide the div on mouse out, in wich case you can use `hover`:

```
$('#categories div').hover(
   function() { //hover in
      $('.box').hide();
      $('#div' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
   }, function(){ //out
      $('.box').hide();
   });
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks! I'm still at the point where I just mashing it all together but am starting to see what's what. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Flexible, generic (and untested!) solution which works with any number of "tabbed" element groups. You just need to specify ".tab-handles a[href=#id_of_target_tab]" hierarchy. As a bonus, the selected tab is remembered between page loads.

```
$(function() {  // Shortcut for $(document).ready()

    $('.tab-handles a').mouseenter(function() {
        // Trigger custom event 'hide' for sibling handles.
        $(this).siblings().trigger('hide');
        // Show current tab.
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    }).bind('hide', function() {
        // Hide the corresponding tab on custom event 'hide'.
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    }).each(function() {
        // Show tab if its id is found in url as an anchor (or hash).
        if (new RegExp($(this).attr('href') + '$')).test(window.location.href))
            $(this).trigger('mouseenter');
    });

})
```

Your page can contain any number of the following structure:

```
<ul class="tab-handles">
    <li><a href="#top-villas"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#villa-specials"></a></li>
</ul>

<div>
    <div id="top-villas"> Your tab content goes here. </div>
    <div id="villa-specials"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for using ul/li instead of nested divs, he'd probably be better off moving in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already had a decent answer and although this isn't jQuery/mooTools - I figured it was worth a mention:

Seven Ways To Hide An Element With Javascript:
http://www.dustindiaz.com/seven-togglers/

:)

Answer (score 0):

onMouseOver isn't a valid jquery method, among other things.

I really recommend browsing with google chrome when you're looking to debug javascript, it's error console is very useful for not just determining errors like this, but also for pinpointing the location in the script that is throwing the error, which might be an advantage beyond Firebug in firefox.

(And you can always run firebug lite as well via the bookmarklet even while using chrome, as the firebug lite website will show: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

Answer (score 0):

I used this to toggle my divs:

html

```
<div class="content-item-news">..</div>
<div class="content-news-extra">...</div>
```

jquery

```
$(".content-item-news").click(function() {
     $(this).next(".content-news-extra").slideToggle(100);
});
```